# Active record test has_many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to test if some entities are properly associated with the owner entity.

```
class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :ingredients
end
```

I've inserted the ingredients and later on want to test if they belong to a given recipe. In cucumber I would like to test something like:

```
recipe.ingredients.should_contain(ingredient1, ingredient2)
```

How can I test this?

Answer (score 0):

This seems more like a unit or integration test and less like a test of behavior. You can use shoulda to test if the relation exists. https://github.com/thoughtbot/shoulda-matchers. Then you can do something like this for a unit test.

```
    recipe.should have_many(:ingredients)
```

On the other hand you can insert the ingredients through an integration test and check the relation on the other side just like you asked in your question.